# Динамически меняющееся содержимое ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview, expandablelistview

Есть такой код, из которого формируется `ExpandableListView`:

```
    private void displayList() {

    // display the list
    loadData();

    // get reference to the ExpandableListView
    myList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableList);
    // create the adapter by passing your ArrayList data
    listAdapter = new MyListAdapter(ScrollFolder.this, parentList);
    // attach the adapter to the list
    myList.setAdapter(listAdapter);

}

private void loadData() {
    ArrayList<ChildRow> childRows = new ArrayList<ChildRow>();
    ParentRow parentRow = null;

    childRows.add(new ChildRow("item 1"));
    childRows.add(new ChildRow("item 2"));
    childRows.add(new ChildRow("item 3"));
    childRows.add(new ChildRow("item 4"));
    childRows.add(new ChildRow("item 5"));
    parentRow = new ParentRow("First Group", childRows);
    parentList.add(parentRow);

    childRows = new ArrayList<ChildRow>();
    childRows.add(new ChildRow("item 6"));
    childRows.add(new ChildRow("item 7"));
    childRows.add(new ChildRow("item 8"));
    childRows.add(new ChildRow("item 9"));
    childRows.add(new ChildRow("item 10"));
    parentRow = new ParentRow("Second Group", childRows);
    parentList.add(parentRow);

    childRows = new ArrayList<ChildRow>();
    childRows.add(new ChildRow("item 11"));
    childRows.add(new ChildRow("item 12"));
    childRows.add(new ChildRow("item 13"));
    childRows.add(new ChildRow("item 14"));
    childRows.add(new ChildRow("item 15"));
    parentRow = new ParentRow("Third Group", childRows);
    parentList.add(parentRow);
}
```

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы данные в `loadData` были прописаны не жестко в коде, а могли подтягиваться динамически? Т.е. нужно, чтобы эти данные могли модифицироваться не за счет изменения кода приложения, а чтобы подтягивались из какой-нибудь `strings.xml` или `SQL` базы данных.

Еще предполагаю, что тут нужен какой-то цикл, который будет пробегаться по переменным `Group` и `item`. Помогите все это правильно реализовать?